# MVC Identity 2.1 - get a list of users NOT in a particular role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

How do I get a list of users that are not in 1 particular role? I am using mvc 5, ef 6, identity 2.1.

To get a list of users in the "Host" role I can do:

```
var getRole = (from r in db.Roles where r.Name.Contains("Host") select r).FirstOrDefault();
var getHostUsers = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(getRole.Id)).ToList();
```

To get a list of all users I can do:

```
var getUsers = await db.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUser).OrderBy(u => u.FirstName).ToListAsync();
```

But what I need is a list of all users that are not in the "Host" role (getUsers - getHostUsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all users, except those with the Host role you can just do the opposite of what you are doing and add an exclamation mark in the where clause.

```
var getRole = (from r in db.Roles where r.Name.Contains("Host") select r).FirstOrDefault();
var getNotHostUsers = db.Users.Where(x => !x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId).Contains(getRole.Id)).ToList();
```